# Get the indices for which any element of k matches a pattern in x[i] in R

Tags: r, match, apply, sapply, grepl

I'm looking for R code that subsets a data frame *a* for indices that match patterns in another vector *k*.

For example, 
consider

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- 1:3
z <- c("foo", "bar", "null")
a <- data.frame(x, y, z)
a
#  x y    z
#1 a 1  foo
#2 b 2  bar
#3 c 3 null
```

Suppose that I have a list that I want to use to subset *a*, where k is defined as

```
k <- c("b", "c")
```

If I use `grepl` with `apply` and `sapply` I can get the rows that match *k*, which is what I want.

```
a[as.logical(apply(sapply(k, grepl, a$x), 1, sum)),]

  x y    z
2 b 2  bar
3 c 3 null
```

This code however, is **REALLY** slow when scaled up to large datasets. Is there a faster and simpler way of doing this?

Thanks,

Rafael

EDIT: I tried my best to find the answer to this question on Stack Overflow. Since I could not find it I can assure that the wording used in this post is unique and therefore a contribution to the forum.

Comment: Please see my edit regarding duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a simple way in base R is to use `%in%`:

```
a[ a$x %in% k , ]
```

Comment: Thanks!! Definitely elegant and simple.